# How to ACCESS .state() in app.js from in your controller to use items from ROUTER

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's my situation...

I have several ROUTES using ANGULAR-UI-ROUTE.

This is only but one example...

```
    }).state('adminwhiteboard', {//ADMIN DASHBOARD WHITEBOARD
        url: "/adminwhiteboard",
        views: {
            "dashContent": {
                templateUrl: "partials/administration/whiteboard/admin-whiteboard-plan-content.html",
                data: {
                    authorization: true, //Authorization REQUIRED
                    redirectTo: 'login', //Go Back to LOGIN PAGE
                    memory: true, //Remember that this user tried!!!
                    pageName: "adminwhiteboard",
                    members: [10, 20, 50, 60]
                },
                controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, $document, $location) {
                    if ($scope.$parent.pagename !== "adminwhiteboard") {
                        $scope.$parent.pagename = "adminwhiteboard";
                        console.log("$STATE PARAMS: ", $stateParams);
                        console.log("$STATE LOC: ", $location);
                        console.log("$STATE LOC: ", $document);

                        //Remove ALL the "IN" for collapse and add back only
                        //for current dropdown
                        $("#mainNavigator li > a").removeClass("in");
                        $("#dropMenu1 li > a").addClass("in");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            id: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
                    console.log("State PageName: ", $stateParams.name);
                    return $stateParams.id; //By putting this here...
                }]
        }
```

The parts are thus:

```
                data: {
                    authorization: true, //Authorization REQUIRED
                    redirectTo: 'login', //Go Back to LOGIN PAGE
                    memory: true, //Remember that this user tried!!!
                    pageName: "adminwhiteboard",
                    members: [10, 20, 50, 60]
                }
```

I want to be able to access the data.authorization, data.redirectTo, data.memory, etc...

From inside my CONTROLLER (not the controller below)

```
                 controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, $document, $location) {
                    if ($scope.$parent.pagename !== "adminwhiteboard") {
                        $scope.$parent.pagename = "adminwhiteboard";
                        console.log("$STATE PARAMS: ", $stateParams);
                        console.log("$STATE LOC: ", $location);
                        console.log("$STATE LOC: ", $document);

                        //Remove ALL the "IN" for collapse and add back only
                        //for current dropdown
                        $("#mainNavigator li > a").removeClass("in");
                        $("#dropMenu1 li > a").addClass("in");
                    }
                }
            }
```

The controller I speak of is another file that is the MAIN CONTROLLER for the entire system.  There are more, of course, but I simply want to access the items in the data: from my controller like so:

$scope.state.currpage, blah, blah, blah.... get me?

By the way, currpage is set every time the user clicks on a ui-sref to change partials in the route.

Thanks, all.

UPDATE:

To answer JC...

I'm doing this... already. So I just need to expand on it?

```
          $scope.changeRoute = function (url) {
                //console.log($scope);
                $location.path(url);
                $timeout(function () {
                    //outside of the digest, by using $timeout(fn, 0, false), where the
                    //false value tells Angular not to wrap this fn in a $apply block:
                    $scope.$apply();
                }, 0, false);

                //ROUTE for Change Start and Change Success
                $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart",
                        function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
                            console.log($scope, $rootScope, $route, $location);
                        });
                $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",
                        function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
                            console.log($scope, $rootScope, $route, $location);
                        });
            };
```

Comment: Use `$stateParams`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set state change event handlers in your controller, and access the data through them.

```
//UI-Router 1.x
$transitions.onSuccess(function(){})

//UI-Router 0.4.x (legacy)
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){});
```

Comment: See UPDATE JC and a confirmation to your question

Comment: Also, I should update my angular-ui-router too as well, which is where KARMA and NPM come in handy so that my libraries update automatically.  Which is what I've done before and should implement here.

Comment: The UI router event is $tateChangeSuccess. $routeChangeSuccess is the event for the built in router.

Comment: HA! So all I need is to flip out $routeChangeSuccess with $stateChangeSuccess and I'm set like flypaper?

Comment: Yes, that should give you access to the `toState` and its associated data.